# It is a good teacher that/who . .

Tags: cleft-constructions

Is it correct to convert "A good teacher knows what his students need" into "It is a good teacher that/who knows what his students need"? Is there a specificity requirement on the post-copular NP in the cleft sentence?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you read my comment below the answer?

Comment: But your comment is far from useful, as it indicates that you don't know what "specific reference" means in linguistic studies.

Comment: Indefinite article in specific reference ; Choosing “a” or “an”. Chicago Manual of Style. That is what I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You require the cleft sentence "It is a good teacher that/who knows what his students need" when you want to focus on the subject or to  put emphasis on the subject : "a good teacher".

Comment: Is there a specificity requirement on the post-copular NP in the cleft sentence?

Comment: Yes, the basic pattern of an IT cleft sentence is :
 
"It + be verb + NP (subject, object, etc)

+ that/who relative clause

Comment: Do you really know what I mean by "specificity requirement"?

Comment: @Apollyon, The post-copular NP (subject, object etc. after the 'be'-verb) is made specific by that/who relative clause. Okay?

Comment: No, that's not what the specificity requirement means.

Comment: What do you mean by 'specificity requirement'?

Comment: If someone said, "I'm looking for a man" at a bar, and another person asked, "Who are you looking for," then "a man" would have specific reference. The speaker wasn't interested in just any man, but a particular man. In a cleft structure, does the post-copular NP beginning with an indefinite article need to have specific reference? That is the question, one so subtle (and out of the ordinary) that only a native speaker could answer.

Comment: You are not going to find the answer in any ESL grammar books. This is not the kind of grammar point covered in ESL materials.

Comment: @Apollyon "specific reference" as used by you is a misnomer here. The point is that you have to **repeat the article, whether definite or indefinite** in order to effect the transformation. "The good men in this world [blah, blah, blah]. It is **the good men in this world** [blah, blah, blah]. It is **a good teacher** [blah, blah, blah].